# Calculating size of particular area below buffer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

I have a point shapefile of villages where data was collected in Northern Kenya. I created a buffer around those villages.

The second vector layer contains polygons defining areas according to vegetation type. So for example, a forest might be surrounded by a narrow ring of woodland in an area which is mainly grassland. I'm trying to obtain a percentage of each vegetation type within the buffer per village.

I'm using QGIS 1.7

Answer (score 11):

You can use the "Intersect" tool on the buffer and land use layers. This should create a third layer where buffers are "cut out of" the land use polygons. Then you can calculate the area of the resulting polygons using Field Calculator.

Village buffer before

[image]

and after the Intersect operation and calculation of area using Field Calculator:

[image]

Divide by the total area of the buffer to obtain percentage values.