# Calculating intersect of two shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, intersection

I have two shapefiles.
1. the clinic buffers 500m area.
2. the postcode area.

Is there a simple way to calculate the intersect two shapefiles ?
I'm using QGIS Dufour. I tried to use fTools to intersect. However, it didn't show me actually how much every piece of the green area. It just combined the fields of two shapefiles.

How do I calculate the intersect of two shapefiles?

[image: intersect two shapefiles]

[image: It just combined the fields of two shapefiles]

I used "Field Calculator" to calculate the intersection with $area. But those numbers are bigger than original area.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the rest of the tools in the Processing Toolbox? Look in Vector -> Overlay. Clip should work.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is there an issue with the geometries in the results or are you just unhappy with the attribute table?

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the area for each of the polygons clipped by the buffer, the answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-a-particular-area-below-a-buffer-in-qgis) might help you.

Comment: The table just show the original area of postcode, I want to calculate the intersection area of postcode.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Use "Field Calculator", it did work. But have to reopen a new file with this intersection shape.

Answer (score 0):

I work with gvSIG, but I think that is similar: use "Clip", not "intersect"