# Intersecting two shape problem using geopandas

Tags: python, shapely, fiona, geopandas

I'm trying to intersect two polygons based on the following link,
[intersecting two shapefiles from Python or command line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178765/intersecting-two-shapefiles-from-python-or-command-line)

But problem occured that shows a "ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file."

I'm new on these free open source GIS tool manipulation, can anyone give me some idea? 
My source code is like this:

```
    from shapely.geometry import shape,Polygon,MultiPolygon,mapping
    import geopandas as gpd

    g1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("./origin_test.shp")
    g2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("./ref_test.shp")

    data=[]
    for index, orig in g1.iterrows():
        for index2, ref in g2.iterrows():
            if ref['geometry'].intersects(orig['geometry']):
               owdspd=orig['wdspd']
               data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].intersection(orig['geometry']),'wdspd':owdspd})

    data = data.set_geometry()
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry','wdspd'])
    df.to_file('./intersection.shp')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) The problem is that the intersection of two polygons is not always a polygon

[image]

```
import geopandas as gp
poly1 = gp.read_file("poly_origin.shp")
poly2 = gp.read_file("poly_test.shp")
data = []
for index, orig in poly1.iterrows():
    for index2, ref in poly2.iterrows():      
        if ref['geometry'].intersects(orig['geometry']): 
         owdspd=orig['id']
         data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].intersection(orig['geometry']),'wdspd':owdspd})

for geom in data: 
   print geom
{'geometry': <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x10aab9c10>, 'wdspd': 1}
{'geometry': <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x10aab9e50>, 'wdspd': 2}
{'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x10aacc250>, 'wdspd': 3}
```

The result is 2 Polygons and a LineString therefore the error

> "ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file"

2) A solution is to convert all the geometries to the same type

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
for i in data:
 geom = i['geometry']
 if geom.geom_type=='Polygon':
      i['geometry']=  LineString(list(geom.exterior.coords))
```

Now, you can convert to a GeoDataFrame

```
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry','wdspd'])
df                          geometry                   wdspd
0  LINESTRING (96.42123294751703 -44.632201588700...      1
1  LINESTRING (282.773470482277 -127.548992317643...      2
2  LINESTRING (144.3726591760299 -221.86142322097...      3
```

3) Or to use [GeoPandas Overlay](http://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/set_operations.html?highlight=overlay#)

```
inter = gp.overlay(poly1, poly2, how='intersection')
inter
     id  id_2                geometry
 0   2     2  POLYGON ((282.773470482277 -127.5489923176438,...
 1   1     1  POLYGON ((51.0880537778328 -116.6195085418168,...
```

### Export the result

```
df.to_file("linestring_intersection.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much, it's really helpful. According to your idea(method 2 and 3), i tried to output the data as shape file in both way with following code:        
        `df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry','wdspd'])`
        `df.to_file('./wdspd_intersection.shp')`
        `f.head()`
 But it failed. Could you mind tell me how to export the result? Thanks...

Comment: look above in Export the result

Comment: Yeah, thanks @gene . I've tried, the linestring is a line, i tried the overlay way, it shows an error like this
   `self.session.start(self, **kwargs)`
  `File "fiona\ogrext.pyx", line 942, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start (fiona/ogrext.c:16386)`
 `ValueError: Null layer:`

Comment: If possible i would like to export in polygons this could make my work more simple.

Comment: If the result contains  other geometries than polygons in the result, you cannot (or try with the solution 3)

Comment: Mérci, solution 3  est un error...

Comment: In addition, how to exclude geometry types other than Ploygon? @gene

Comment: It would be nice to exclude line geometry types... probably possible with a simple test but I do not know how.