# Excluding multi geometry types into a single Polygon type

Tags: python, shapely, fiona, geopandas

After i did an intersection with two shape using geopandas through the following topic ([Intersecting two shape problem using geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230494/intersecting-two-shape-problem-using-geopandas)). But it output a multi geometry type shape,which in futher step will impossible export to polygon.
Results show as below:

```
for i in data:
   geom = i['geometry']
   print geom
```

Output:

```
POLYGON ((139.9125 40.592043, 139.925 40.592043, 139.925 40.58371, 139.9125 40.58371, 139.9125 40.592043))
POINT (139.9125 40.58371)
LINESTRING (139.9125 40.58371, 139.925 40.58371)
```

How can i exclude Point and LineString from multi-types into a single geometry type as polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to exclude all the geometries that are not polygons

```
for i in data:
   geom = i['geometry']
   if geom.geom_type=='Polygon':
      print geom
```

#### Return only Polygon geometries

```
data_ok= []
for i in data:
   if i['geometry'].geom_type=='Polygon':
       data_ok.append(i)
```

or in one line with list comprehensions, in one line

```
 data_ok= [i for i in data if i['geometry'].geom_type=='Polygon']
```

And you can eliminate a loop in your original script

```
data = []
for index, orig in poly1.iterrows():
    for index2, ref in poly2.iterrows():      
        if ref['geometry'].intersects(orig['geometry']): 
             if ref['geometry'].intersection(orig['geometry']).geom_type=='Polygon':
                owdspd=orig['id']
                data.append({'geometry':ref['geometry'].intersection(orig['geometry']),'wdspd':owdspd})
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I know this print will works, but how to return and set the intersected data only holds polygon geometry?

Comment: With another list, for example, look above

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much, i've got the problem solved, it works.
But as usual, the output to_file method always show an error like this:
        
         ` self.session.start(self, **kwargs)`
         `File "fiona\ogrext.pyx", line 942, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start (fiona/ogrext.c:16386)`
         `ValueError: Null layer`

Comment: `df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,columns=['geometry','wdspd'])`
     df.to_file('./wdspd_intersection.shp')`
         
          `df.head()`