# Removing polygons from GeoDataFrame which do not intersect with any polygons of other GeoDataFrame using Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, overlapping-features, geodataframe

I am looking for an efficient way to remove any polygons from a `GeoDataFrame` which do not intersect with any polygons of another `GeoDataFrame`. I tried it the following way which seems really inefficient.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf1 = gdp.read_file('./my_geodataframe1.gpkg')
gdf2 = gdp.read_file('./my_geodataframe2.gpkg')

gdf2_dissolved = gdf2.dissolve()
indices_to_remove = []

for index, row in gdf1.iterrows():
    polygon = row['geometry']
    if not gdf2_dissolved.intersects(polygon)[0]:
        indices_to_remove.append(index)
```

Is there any quicker way to do so?

Comment: You can try this one liner, but I think internally it's just a for loop, so may not be any quicker.

`gdf1 = gdf1[gdf1.geometry.intersects(gdf2_dissolved)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spatial join is very fast. Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import os
folder = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/data/LMV/Topografi100/Topografi_100_Sverige_230721"

df1 = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(folder, "mark_sverige.gpkg"), layer="markframkomlighet")
df2 = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(folder, "naturvard_sverige.gpkg"), layer="skyddadnatur")

print(df1.shape)
#(3320, 5)

#Create an id column to filter by after the spatial join
df1["tempid"] = range(df1.shape[0]) 

#Spatial join with predicate "inner" to only keep features intersecting
matches = gpd.sjoin(left_df=df1, right_df=df2, how="inner").tempid #A Series of tempids in df1 intersecting df2

#Select, and drop tempid column
df1 = df1.loc[df1.tempid.isin(matches)].drop(columns="tempid")

print(df1.shape)
#(1623, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions, see [Intersecting two shape problem using geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230494/intersecting-two-shape-problem-using-geopandas) for example

Generally, `iterrows` should only be used in specific cases ([How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas))

In addition to Bera's solution, you can use the [`apply function`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and the simple [`unary_union`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union) property

[image]

```
gdf1 = gpd.read_file('stac1.shp')
gdf2 = gpd.read_file('stac2.shp')
uu = gdf1.unary_union
gdf2['inter'] = gdf2['geometry'].apply(lambda row: row.intersects(uu))
# polygons from gdf2 which do not intersect with any polygons of gdf1
print(gdf2.loc[gdf2.inter == 0]
   id  ori              geometry                                inter
2   3  gdf2  POLYGON ((-1.095 0.843, -0.376 0.760, -1.022 0...  False
3   2  gdf2  POLYGON ((-0.417 -0.616, 0.173 -0.912, -0.398 ...  False
```

Another solution is to use a simple for loop (without iterating over the GeoDataFrame):

```
 indices_to_remove = []
 for i,geom in enumerate(list(gdf2.geometry)):
      if not geom.intersects(uu):
           print(i)
           indices_to_remove.append(i)
 2
 3
 print(gdf2.iloc[indices_to_remove])
    id   ori           geometry
 2   3  gdf2  POLYGON ((-1.095 0.843, -0.376 0.760, -1.022 0...  
 3   2  gdf2  POLYGON ((-0.417 -0.616, 0.173 -0.912, -0.398 ...
```